# Get queryset in categorize form with having list of items in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My person Model is here:

```
class person(models.Model):
        interests = models.ManyToManyField(Ineterest, default=None)
```

and Interest Model:

```
class Interest(models.Model):
        interest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and article Model is here:

```
class Article(models.Model):
        category = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, default=None)
```

I just want to filter articles in categorize form having a list of all articles related with it example is:
`[{'category': 'Finance', 'articles': ['article obj-1', 'article obj-2']}, {'category': 'Business', 'articles': ['article obj-1', 'article obj-2', 'article obj-3']}]`

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by accessing reverse many-to-many.
`prefetch_related` is required to avoid making multiple queries.

```
qs = Interest.objects.prefetch_related('article_set')
[{'category': i.interest, 'articles': [a for a in i.article_set.all()]} for i in qs]
```

Comment: great but when I will use in production version it will take time to fetch articles from my AWS DB due to the ForLoop so is there any way to fetch the same queryset without ForLoop

Comment: This will only create 2 database queries irrespective of how many Articles and Interests you have. `prefetch_related` will take care of that

Comment: ok, I will implement that, and let's see how effective this query is?

Comment: Yes. you can use django-debug-toolbar to monitor the database queries it creates.